# Сохранение ng-model в ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

Добрый день. А можно еще раз объяснить про динамические модели в формах?
 Хочу сохранить в mongoose

```
     name: type {}, 
           required : "Please fill name"
```

Имя (name) у меня может быть на разных языках для чего я делаю

```
       <form name="ConditionForm">
             <div ng-repeat="vm in availableLanguages track by $index">
                <md-input-container flex>  
                   <label>{{vm}}</label> 
                   {{name[vm]}} 

               <input ng-model="name[$index]">

               </md-input-container> 

             </div>

              <md-button ng-click="create()" class="md-primary">
               Добавить
           </md-button> 
           </form>
```

где

```
    availableLanguages = ['ru','en','de','fr']
```

Но форма возвращает пустой name в запросе. Как это победить?

**Обновление**

Сдуру сам скопировал с `plankera`, но там уже просто пробовал. Ошибка в том, что я ставил `name[$index]` - а мне нужно что то поставить, чтобы возвращало `"ru" : "Слово","en":"Word"`. Т.е. не индекс массива, а "название". Чтобы сохранять в базе `name: [{"ru":"Слово"},{"en":"word"}]`

Answer (score 1):

Странно, вот ссылочка на `fiddle` (https://jsfiddle.net/odgofrdt/1/) - там все ок.

Html

```
<body ng-app="core" ng-controller="MainController">
    <form name="langForm">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="lang in langs track by $index">
                <label>{{ lang }}</label>
                <input ng-model="name[$index]" />
            </li>
        </ul>

        <button ng-click="create()">submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('core', []);
angular.module('core')
.controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.langs = ['ru', 'en'];
    $scope.name = [];

    $scope.create = function(){
        console.log($scope.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Да, я неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Обновил.